# ActionController::UrlGenerationErr or: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"} missing required keys: [:user_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest

I'm getting the error  `ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"profiles"} missing required keys: [:user_id]`  in the test for my user sign up. The user is redirected to the user's profile after sign up but my test is failing. Below are some lines of my code..

CREATE ACTION IN SESSIONS CONTROLLER

```
def create
  user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
  if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
    log_in user
   params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
   redirect_back_or user_profile_path(user, @profile)
  else 
   flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
   render 'new'
end
```

CREATE ACTION IN USER CONTROLLER

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if @user.save
    log_in @user
    flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Mini Olympics"
    redirect_to user_profile_path(current_user, @profile)
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

THE SIGNUP TEST (WITH VALID INFORMATION)

```
test "valid signup information" do
  get signup_path
  assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
  post_via_redirect user_profile_path, user: { email: "user@example.com",
                     password:  "password",
                     password_confirmation: "password", 
                     profile_atrributes: {user_id: @user.id, name: "Example Test", street: "24 Fred Rd", city: "Cutlin", state: "SW", zipcode: "35478"}}
  end
  assert_template 'profiles/show'
  assert is_logged_in?
end
```

The test fails at the line `post_via_redirect` but the actually application works.

Comment: @trh, no its not. i also tried `user.id` to the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the test, the `user_profile_path` is missing its parameters. It should be

```
post_via_redirect user_profile_path(user), user: { ... }
```

Comment: you are right but i noticed `POST` only works with `:create` action but with my code the profile wasn't been created. Thanks.